# LINUX Remove text sections from file with sed based on

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, sed

I have big text file (471 615 lines). Its stucture is like:

```
use TABLE1/*!*/
good code here
use mysql/*!*/
bad code here
use TABLE1/*!*/
good code here
use mysql/*!*/ 
...
...
```

how to remove "bad code" sections? Offcourse i know this would be kind of loop with regex but how to make it? I already used bash loops to build similar file from mysql binary log files and cut out some content with sed based on their line numbers but this file has too many occurencies to cut them out by lines numbers.

PS. I just done it manually for 1 month period and there is 23 occurences of "bad code". There are 6 months to fix so aproximately there will be 130-140 occurencies. As you see i would have to spend whole day to root them out manually

Comment: Bad code is every line after "use mysql" line up to first occurence "use TABLE1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried RomanPerekhres and Raman Sailopal solutions. First cut too much (some headers at the beginning of the file. Second did fine job but left some occurencies. I didnt try to analyze why, but just changed strategy. I just cut out every line with containing some specific words like GRANT TO, FUNCTION, CREATE USER, DROP USER, PRIVILEGES etc (with sed offcourse). This way i cut out all commands connected with mysql table.

Thank you all for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Simple ***awk*** approach:

Sample file `testfile`:

```
use TABLE1/*!*/
select user_id
from 
system_users
use mysql/*!*/
drop database
delete * from users
delete id from system_users
use TABLE1/*!*/
select
   sum(price)
from
   orders
use mysql/*!*/
update users
   set id = "bad boy"
drop table users
```

---

The job:

```
awk '/^use TABLE/{ f=1 }/^use mysql/{ print; f=0 }f' testfile
```

The output:

```
use TABLE1/*!*/
select user_id
from 
system_users
use mysql/*!*/
use TABLE1/*!*/
select
   sum(price)
from
   orders
use mysql/*!*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^use/h;G;/^use mysql/M!P;d' file
```

Append the `use` statement to each and every line and only print those lines that do not contain `use mysql` in the appended part.

Answer (score 0):

Another sed approach

```
sed '/use mysql\/*!*\//,/use TABLE1\/*!*\//{//!d}' filename
```

Search for everything between use mysql... and use TABLE1... then delete everything apart from the lines containing the search patterns.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for `s/old/new/`, that is all. You aren't doing `s/old/new/` so you shouldn't be considering using sed. Just use awk:

```
$ awk '/^use mysql/{f=1} /^use TABLE1/{f=0} !f' file
use TABLE1/*!*/
good code here
use TABLE1/*!*/
good code here
```

If you like golf you can reduce that to just:

```
$ awk '/^use/{f=/mysql/}!f' file
use TABLE1/*!*/
good code here
use TABLE1/*!*/
good code here
```